# SimpleCursorAdapter with CheckBox

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

Any idea how this is done? I'm currently using a SimpleCursorAdapter for my listview and using 1 and 0 as the current state for my list, where 1 is being on the list and 0 for not, when the delete button is clicked, the chosen items in the checkbox will be deleted from the list and the value will be set to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your customAdpater update the code

```
SparseBooleanArray sba=new SparseBooleanArray(); // declare globally in adapter
convertview.onClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick()
{
 if(checkbox.isChecked())
 {
   sba.put(position,true);
 }
  else
 {
  sba.put(position,false);
 }

});
```

**on delete button click method**

```
deletebutton.onClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
  for(int position=0;position<array.size();position++) 
  {
    if(array.get(position))
    {
        //checked so set it to 1
     }
     else
      {
     //  not checked make it to 0
      }
   }
}
```